# Comparing a string from a file and a malloced string in C

Tags: c, string, function, substring

I am trying to iterate over a text file and for each row, check if a specific substring
that was created with memory allocation is within it.
my problem is that in order for the string of the malloc to be intact, I need to add \0 in the end of it.
Because otherwise it will include some gibberish letters at the end.
This causes my use of strstr irrelevant because it searches for that string but with an additional \0 in the end which causes the search to fail.

```
int compare(char *X,char *Y,int size)
{
    while (size >0 && *X && *Y)
    {
        if (*X != *Y)
            return 0;
        X++;
        Y++;
        size--;
    }
    return (*Y == '\0');
}

char* substring(char* X, char* Y, int size)
{
    while (*X != '\0')
    {
        if (compare(X, Y, size))
        {
            printf("in\n");
            return X;
        }
        X++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

and for the actual calling:

```
if (substring(temp, lua_name, strlen(lua_name)-1) != NULL)
{
  puts(temp);
}
```

**for example:**

```
payloadSubtree:add(roy_fields.my_data_req,buffer(offset,2))
my_data_req\0
```

How do I solve this? how can I ignore the \0 of the second string in order to find it within a file while iterating over it?

Comment: Why are you adding `/0`, not `\0`?

Comment: may be you mean `strlen(lua_name) - 1` inplace of `strlen(lua_name - 1)`

Comment: `strlen(lua_name - 1)` Why subtract from *the string*? Did you mean to subtract from the `strlen` result instead? Even if so, why? `strlen` does not count the NUL terminator.

Comment: @MikeCAT yes i fixed it now , sorry wrote it wrong in here .

Comment: @IrAM fixed it , miss copied it

Comment: @kaylum yeah i miss copied it , I was just playing with it honestly , i'm not really sure how can I send to a function a new value without the last character of the \0 without that being with garbage values at the end of it , have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strnstr` instead of `strstr`, and search for `strlen(str)` chars.

Comment: Hey @Tsak i've used an online implementation from stackoverflow of strnstr with a call for the function like this printf("%d\n", strnstr("hey p_type yo", lua_name, strlen(lua_name)) == NULL ? 0 : 1);   but it still failed to identify it within a string and returned 0 . the lua_name holds the p_type\0 . am I missing something ?   Would love to hear your thoughts !

Comment: well i'm quite noob, indeed the strnstr is not the right solution, for it will only search on n char into the string that contains the file's text, as Erdal Küçük suggest , memmem() could interest you for you can search n char of needle into n char of haystack, i guess you get the number of chars in the txt file when you read it and put it into your buffer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to operate on nul-terminated arrays: `strstr`
If you want to operate on size specified arrays: `memmem`

Comment: In C teamülünde, a function having an alternative involving the letter of "n" in its name , e.g. `strnstr`,  should be preferred over that not of.

Comment: @snr I thought `strnstr` is BSD only? In the C Standard (C11 Draft N1570) i can't find `strnstr` . The question has no tag 'bsd', only 'c'.

Comment: @snr Ok, I can agree with that.